# Altera Quartus 13.1

Tags: 16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have installed Quartus 13.1 without any problem. It started properly after installation. But after rebooting the computer, Quartus is lost. It does not show in the search or on the desktop. I can not find any starter in the folder installed. I will be very glad for your helps.

Comment: Usually such software is installed somewhere in `/opt`. You can try to search its folder here. Then launch it with for example `/opt/altera/quartus131/bin/quartus` or similar.

Comment: When I can't find something like this on my system, I run `sudo updatedb` and then `locate -b 'quartus' | less` (or whatever I'm looking for). `updatedb` refreshes the database that `locate` uses to search your system. `locate` uses that database to search for things very quickly - much faster than using `find`. The `-b` tells it to only look at the last component of the path so it will ignore results where the target is found in the directory portion of the path. `less` pages the output in case there's more than will fit on one screen.

Comment: I searched "quartus" in computer but not found.  Also , not in the /opt unfortunately. Thanks for your help

Comment: I have tried updatedb, it found some dot files. But probably not application.